# .htaccess and DirectoryIndex

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have a two files in my root folder: `main.html` and `index.php`.
Well, normally `index.php` takes places as it has higher priority to respond, just wanted to change the logic, so then at first the user has to visit the `main.html` and then get redirected to `index.php`. I tried the below code in my `.htaccess` but it doesn't work as I expected. Actually after doing that, now the first page is correctly changed to `main.html`, but it never get redirected to index.php!!! It actually returns to `main.html` again and again (like loop!)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex main.html /main.html
```

ps:

1- even if i try to request the index.php it will open main.html instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default page for directory using the following in your htaccess file, as you have done in the question. Users would land on main.html (instead of index.php) when navigating to "www.coolsite.com/".

```
//Change default directory page
DirectoryIndex main.html
```

To redirect the user  to another page, you can use the following:

```
window.location = "http://www.coolsite.com/index.php";
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, so as I mentioned it is done by adding DirectoryIndex into htaccess file, but the problem is that the page will never get redirected to index.php (I've used same javascript). it actually returns to main.html again ... I guess it has something to do with RewriteRules i have used in htaccess. please be noted i still need that part for handling permalinks in the site.

Comment: just small query: does these two scripts getting handled differently for webserver: window.location = "http://www.coolsite.com/index.php"; and window.location = "index.php"; ? i'm asking this because right now I've done this with second code.

Comment: same issue i think: http://serverfault.com/questions/469339/static-site-to-dynamic-rewrite-loop

Comment: removed DirectoryIndex line from .htaccess , renamed main.html to index.html (index.html has higher priority than index.php) , result is quite same as before ... redirect loop ..

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems wordpress and static content [index page!] does not not come along! (mostly because of the existing RewriteRule[s] + WP internals)

The workaround is to create a 'page template' (the static content you wish to display as index page) and ask WP to display it as Front-page .